# Find the condition that the line $lx+my+n=0$ is a tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

> Find the condition that the line $lx+my+n=0$ is a tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

My Attempt:
\begin{align}lx+my+n&=0\\
y&=\dfrac {-n-lx}{m}\end{align}

Now, 
\begin{align}x^2+y^2&=r^2\\
x^2+(\dfrac {-n-lx}{m})^2&=r^2\\
x^2+\dfrac {n^2+2nlx+l^2x^2}{m^2} &=r^2\\
x^2(m^2+l^2) + 2nlx +n^2-m^2r^2&=0\end{align}

How do I continue further?

Comment: You may want to check:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254073/the-line-y-mxc-is-a-tangent-to-x2y2-a2-if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line is tangent to the circle, if its distance to the center $(0,0) $ equals the radius $r :$

$$\frac{|l.0+m.0+n|}{\sqrt {l^2+m^2}}=r $$

or
$$n^2=r^2 (l^2+m^2) $$

Answer (score 1):

Compute the discriminant of your last expression and make it equal to zero. That's the condition for tangency.

Comment: Could you please show me the calculations? I am.not getting that.

Comment: @AlbertEinstein there's not a lot to show. The discriminant equal to zero implies that there's only one value of $x$ that satisfies the equation of the line and the equation of the circle. That's the key.

Comment: BTW @Salahamam_Fatima 's answer is more elegant and intuitive. I was just working over your approach

Answer (score 0):

Equation of tangent in point of contact $(x_1,y_1)$ form can be written as 
$$xx_1+yy_1-r^2=0$$
Since $lx+my+n =0 $ also represent the same tangent .
$$\implies \frac{x_1}{l}=\frac{y_1}{m}=\frac{-r^2}{n}$$
Now you can find point of contact ,and it lies on circle so it satisfies the equation of circle .That will be required condition.