# Find the equations to lines that are tangent to a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

> The circle has equation $(x-6)^2+(y-5)^2=17$.
>   The lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ are each a tangent to the circle and intersect at the point $(0,12)$. Find the equation of $L_1$ and $L_2$  giving your answer in the form $y=my+c$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254073/the-line-y-mxc-is-a-tangent-to-x2y2-a2-if

Answer (score 2):

Any line through the point $(0,12)$ which is not vertical has equation
$y=mx+12$ with $m\in\mathbb{R}$. A line is tangent to the circle $(x-6)^2+(y-5)^2=17$ if and only if it intersects the circle at just one point. That is, if and only if, the following quadratic equation in $x$ has just one root
$$(x-6)^2+((mx+12)-5)^2=17.$$
Can you take it from here? Give it a try and show your work!

Comment: I can’t get it. The answers are L1 y= -4x+12 and L2 y= -8x/19+12

Comment: I expanded what you said

Comment: @Lynette Please re-edit your question and, below it, show your work so far. Let's see what it going wrong.

Comment: Simplified to x^2+m^2x^2-12x+14mx+38=0 using the fact that the discriminate must be 0

Comment: @Lynette It should be 68 and not 38. What is the discriminant then?

Comment: Thanks Robert. I can’t send the picture but you could sketch it. Sketch a circle at (6,5) and draw two tangents to the circle. These two tangents intersect at (0,12)

Comment: Ohhh, you’re so right. It is 68 not 38....sorry such a stupid error

Comment: Well done. Now evaluate the discriminant. As you said, it has to be zero.

Comment: I got it!!! Thanks Robert....you’re a STAR

Comment: @Lynette Glad to be useful. BTW, if you are new here, welcome to MSE and please take a few seconds for a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour