# Quadratic equation solving

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

How to prove that the value of x from $x^{2}+y^{2}=a^{2}$ and $y=mx+c$ are equal when $c^{2}=a^{2}(m^2+1)$?

I tried to equate the x from both variables but can't get it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254073/the-line-y-mxc-is-a-tangent-to-x2y2-a2-if

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+(mx+c)^2=a^2$$
$$(1+m^2)x^2+(2mc)x+(c^2-a^2)=0$$
This has a single solution when the determinant of the quadratic is zero i.e.
$$(2mc)^2-4(1+m^2)(c^2-a^2)=0$$
$$4m^2c^2-4(c^2-a^2+m^2c^2-m^2a^2)=0$$
$$m^2c^2-c^2+a^2-m^2c^2+m^2a^2=0$$
$$c^2=a^2(m^2+1)$$

Comment: I can understand your method but please read the question once. It is given that $$c^{2}=a^{2}(m^{2}+1)$$ and you have to prove the other thing. But you have given the vice versa.

Comment: Your answer is correct for the question" give the condition for which value of x from the equations given above are equal."

Answer (score 0):

The first locus is a circle and the second is a straight line. As shown in the post pointed to by @lab, the condition between the parameters expresses that the line tangents the circle.

This doesn't mean at all that "the values of $x$ are equal".